# R append 2 data frames with different columns

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr, rbind

I would like to append dfToAdd to df, where the first has missing columns. Important detail is that df has 2 types of columns. 1st set of columns are correlating with each other.
e.g. group="A" means name="Group A" and color="Blue". There can't be a combination of A-Group A-Red.
2nd type of columns are correlating among themselves.
animal="Dog" action="Bark"
And I would like to add this second data frame with missing columns of the first type of columns. Those columns should be filled with combinations of the first type of columns like the following dfResult (order of rows don't matter):

```
df = data.frame(group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"),
                name = c("Group A", "Group A", "Group A", "Group B", "Group B", "Group B"),
                color = c("Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Red", "Red", "Red"),
                animal = c("Dog", "Cat", "Mouse", "Dog", "Cat", "Mouse"),
                action = c("Bark", "Meow", "Squeak", "Bark", "Meow", "Squeak")
                )

dfToAdd = data.frame(animal = c("Lion", "Bird"), 
                     action = c("Roar", "Chirp"))

dfResult = data.frame(group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B"),
                      name = c("Group A", "Group A", "Group A", "Group B", "Group B", "Group B", "Group A", "Group A", "Group B", "Group B"),
                      color = c("Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Blue", "Blue", "Red", "Red"),
                      animal = c("Dog", "Cat", "Mouse", "Dog", "Cat", "Mouse", "Lion", "Bird", "Lion", "Bird"),
                      action = c("Bark", "Meow", "Squeak", "Bark", "Meow", "Squeak", "Roar", "Chirp", "Roar", "Chirp"))
> df
  group    name color animal action
1     A Group A  Blue    Dog   Bark
2     A Group A  Blue    Cat   Meow
3     A Group A  Blue  Mouse Squeak
4     B Group B   Red    Dog   Bark
5     B Group B   Red    Cat   Meow
6     B Group B   Red  Mouse Squeak
> dfToAdd
  animal action
1   Lion   Roar
2   Bird  Chirp
> dfResult
   group    name color animal action
1      A Group A  Blue    Dog   Bark
2      A Group A  Blue    Cat   Meow
3      A Group A  Blue  Mouse Squeak
4      B Group B   Red    Dog   Bark
5      B Group B   Red    Cat   Meow
6      B Group B   Red  Mouse Squeak
7      A Group A  Blue   Lion   Roar
8      A Group A  Blue   Bird  Chirp
9      B Group B   Red   Lion   Roar
10     B Group B   Red   Bird  Chirp
```

But the 1st type of columns (group, name, color) is not completely known. I am working with multiple grouping variables of an arbitrary number. You can imagine that there may or may not be be a description column="Group A is a good group" or date="2020.04.13". We only know for sure the columns of the second type: animal and action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do this in a single `%>%` by `slice`ing the first row from 'df', `select` the columns that are not the ones in 'dfToAdd', bind that with the 'dfToAdd', then do the row bind with 'df' and use `complete`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(rlang)
library(purrr)
df %>%
       slice(1) %>%
       select(-names(dfToAdd)) %>%  
       uncount(nrow(dfToAdd))  %>%     
       bind_cols(dfToAdd) %>%
       bind_rows(df, .) %>% 
       complete(nesting(!!! syms(names(dfToAdd))), 
             nesting(!!! syms(setdiff(names(.), names(dfToAdd)))))
# A tibble: 10 x 5
#   animal action group name    color
# * <fct>  <fct>  <fct> <fct>   <fct>
# 1 Cat    Meow   A     Group A Blue 
# 2 Cat    Meow   B     Group B Red  
# 3 Dog    Bark   A     Group A Blue 
# 4 Dog    Bark   B     Group B Red  
# 5 Mouse  Squeak A     Group A Blue 
# 6 Mouse  Squeak B     Group B Red  
# 7 Bird   Chirp  A     Group A Blue 
# 8 Bird   Chirp  B     Group B Red  
# 9 Lion   Roar   A     Group A Blue 
#10 Lion   Roar   B     Group B Red
```

Comment: I have updated my answer for the problem of using unknown column names. It needs to be dynamic. I don't really know "group, name, color". But I can have them in a character vector.

Comment: @Genom.  which of the nesting you want to change

Comment: I know about animal and action. So nesting(animal, action) is fine. However, nesting(group, name, color) can be more. Like nesting(group, name, color, description, date, location...). Actually it would be all the missing columns in dfToAdd comapred to df.

Comment: I am getting Error: Argument 2 must be length 1, not 2 at bind_cols.

Comment: @Genom it could be a version issue.  can you try with `uncount` in the updated

Comment: Meanwhile, I have found this: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/4527

Comment: @Genom yes, that should work as well.  Also, `uncount`, should work

Comment: I accepted since this is the simplest answer. I am updating my answer with sym as an aternative. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh, just realized that there are issues if the df is grouped. df %>% ungroup() %>% ... is enough. Otherwise, slice returns multiple rows (1 for each group).

Comment: @Genom yes, you are right.  the group attributes needs to be removed with `ungroup`

Answer (score 1):

While writing this I had the idea to use `[nesting][1]` on both sides of `[complete][2]` function of tidyr and detect missing columns manually (maybe there is a more elegant solution):

```
# First find all grouping columns
groupCols = colnames(df)[!(colnames(df) %in% colnames(dfToAdd))]
otherCols = colnames(df)[colnames(df) %in% colnames(dfToAdd)]
# Populate missing columns with first grouping appearing in the df
dfToAdd[groupCols] = df[1, groupCols]
# rbind it to append
dfResult = rbind(df, dfToAdd)
# Now we have obvious missing combinations, tidyr::complete accepts nesting information to generate combinations only for those, which needs to be different.
dfResult %>% tidyr::complete(tidyr::nesting(!!! syms(otherCols)), tidyr::nesting(!!! syms(groupCols)))
```

edit: actually realized that I am using unknown column names at the end. This doesn't work really. I need to feed groupCols (character vector) to second nesting call.

edit2: now thanks to akrun's answer, I can correct this one too.